# There is no "Clear date" in data limit in ZTE Router

Tags: router

I bought a ZTE MF980 router this week. The problem is that there is no way to set `Clear date` at all.

The data limit resets on the 1st of the month, while the provider resets my data limit on the 14th of the month.

The first picture is from my router, which does not have `Clear date`. The second picture is of another router that has the option.

Without `Clear date`:
[image: Without "Clear date"]

With `Clear date`:
[image: With "Clear date"]

Can this be resolved?

Comment: Have you asked ZTE the reason your model’s firmware doesn’t have the option you’re looking for?

Comment: I sent an email to zte.
If I get an answer I will not hesitate to share here

Comment: What exactly did you ask?

Comment: I asked like here.
They asked for the IMEI of my device and also a model.
I gave it, and they told me it was an unregistered device.